# Powershell Copy-Item using variables for destination

Tags: excel, csv, powershell, variables

I am attempting to copy a file from a VM that I am able to access with my script to a network drive that I am also able to access with my script if I put them in manually, I have a few thousand users so I'd like to write a script to pull from a csv and copy the files. I keep running into Cannot Convert system.object when it comes to the destination. Below is my script and part of the csv.

```
$Credential = Get-Credential

$Datamigrate = Import-CSV  "\\H:\Test\Jon.Doe\PLCXX-XXVM.csv"

$DesktopPath = $Datamigrate|Select DesktopPath

$HomeDrivePath = $Datamigrate|Select HomeDrivePath

Copy-Item $DesktopPath -Destination $HomeDrivePath -Recurse
```

[image: Error Capture]

[image: Excel Capture]

Comment: `|Select -ExpandProperty HomeDrivePath`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$Credential = Get-Credential

(Import-CSV  "\\H:\Test\Jon.Doe\PLCXX-XXVM.csv") |
% {Copy-Item $_.DesktopPath -Destination $_.HomeDrivePath -Recurse}
```

This should repeat the copy once for each record in the csv file, something I imagine you intend to do.

Comment: `%` is the pipeline alias for `foreach-object` so whats happening is we are saying foreach line in the csv call `Copy-item` and `$_` represents the current line in the loop.